# How to add multiple Children to flutter scaffold body

Tags: flutter, scaffold

I am trying to write multiple `child` to `flutter` scaffold `body:` tag.

I am new to flutter and I don't know how to do multiple children inside a body tag.
his is what I have tried.

```
return new Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        leading: new Icon(Icons.live_tv),
        title: const Text('SnapNews'),
        backgroundColor: Colors.red,
        actions: <Widget>[
          IconButton(
            icon: Icon(Icons.help),
            onPressed: () {
              Navigator.push(
                  context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_) => Help()));
            },
          ),
        ],
      ),
      body: new ListView.builder(
        itemCount: 10,
        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
          return new GestureDetector(
            onTap: () {
              print("tapped");
            },
            child: new Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
              child: new Container(
                color: Colors.grey,
                height: 100.0,
              ),
            ),
          );
        },
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton.extended(
        elevation: 4.0,
        icon: const Icon(Icons.camera_enhance),
        label: const Text('Snap'),
        backgroundColor: Colors.red,
        onPressed: () {
          Navigator.push(
            context,
            MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_) => CameraScreen()),
          );
        },
      ),
      floatingActionButtonLocation: FloatingActionButtonLocation.centerDocked,
      bottomNavigationBar: BottomAppBar(
        child: new Row(
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
          children: <Widget>[
            IconButton(
              icon: Icon(null),
              onPressed: () {},
            ),
            IconButton(
              icon: Icon(null),
              onPressed: () {},
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
```

And this produces a GUI as below:

[image]

But I want to add a `Search Bar` on the top of this `ListView`

How can I do this with adding another child/children to the `body:` tag

[image]

Thank you.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could put the ListView.builder inside a ListView.

Edit: To make the SearchBar() not scrollable, put it inside Column instead of ListView.

```
        body: Column(
          children: [
            SearchBar(),
            Expanded(
              child: ListView.builder(
                itemCount: 10,
                itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                  return new GestureDetector(
                    onTap: () {
                      print("tapped");
                    },
                    child: new Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                      child: new Container(
                        color: Colors.grey,
                        height: 100.0,
                      ),
                    ),
                  );
                },
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
```

Comment: When I do this, I can't see anything. Body part is empty just plain white.

Comment: Okay this works, how can I make the search bar static? it also goes down when I scroll

Comment: @JananathBanuka How did you fix the empty body bug? I'm having the same problem

Answer (score 8):

you need to give `body` a `Column` widget as a child and then you can use as many children as you want.

example

```
Scaffold(
  body: Column(
    children: <Widget>[
      //all the children widgets that you need
    ],
  ),
),
```

Comment: this doesn't work. only gives white space doesn't even show what I had before

Answer (score 0):

The recommended way is that you put the search bar inside the `AppBar` widget inside the `title`. Right now you are using this `title: const Text('SnapNews'),` so what you can do is toggle between the `Text('SnapNes')` widget and the seachbar let say `TextField` widget. Put a `search button` and a `cancel button` in the `actions` in the AppBar to get the desired effect. For example:

```
bool isSearching = false;

appBar: AppBar(
    title: !isSearching
        ? Text('SnapNews')
        : TextField(
            onChanged: (value) {
              // search logic
            },
            style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
            decoration: InputDecoration(
                icon: Icon(
                  Icons.search,
                  color: Colors.white,
                ),
                hintText: "Search News Here",
                hintStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.white)),
          ),
    actions: <Widget>[
      isSearching
          ? IconButton(
              icon: Icon(Icons.cancel),
              onPressed: () {
                setState(() {
                  this.isSearching = false;
                });
              },
            )
          : IconButton(
              icon: Icon(Icons.search),
              onPressed: () {
                setState(() {
                  this.isSearching = true;
                });
              },
            )
    ],
  ),
```

Check the following [link.](https://github.com/bitfumes/flutter-country-house/blob/master/lib/Screens/AllCountries.dart)